# How do I get a client ID for the GDocs API?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to get set up on the Google Docs API but I cannot obtain a Client ID. Whenever I go into the 'Browser' Quickguide, and click on 'Enable Google Docs API', a window pops up that says 'Configure your OAuth client' but I can't actually do anything in the window (no clicks, no keyboard input, no anything).

I'd be grateful for some guidance as to what my next steps should be.

Comment: are you following any tutorial? a ClientID usually can be retrieved from console.cloud.google.com when you setup a GCP project but it depends on what are you trying to do. Share more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that button is not working. You can configure it manually and get the client ID following these steps:

1) In Cloud Platform console create a new cloud project [1].

2) In this project, search for Docs API and click on enable button [2].

3) Finally set-up the oauth credentials and from there you obtain the client ID [3].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects

[2] https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/enable-disable-apis

[3] https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849